# [SQL]With AFTER INSERT, I'm trying to update specific row of Table A after inserting new row into Table B

Tags: sql, database, triggers

I'm currently creating an inventory management database which has two tables. One table shows the products that are currently in supply with specific quantities. The second table is for submitting tickets that will remove a certain quantity of a product.

I'm trying to trigger the AFTER INSERT into Table B, where inserting the value of 20 will then subtract 20 from the corresponding *LotNum* row in Table A

Table A:

| LotNum | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1251 | 40 |
| 1125 | 30 |

Table B:

| LotNum | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1251 | 20 |

Table A after trigger:

| LotNum | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1251 | 20 |
| 1125 | 30 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: And show us your current code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged your DMBS so this is a SQL Server example. The syntax is different for other DBMSes so this will not work on those

I have added an (untested) MySQL example at the end also

The below trigger will do what you need to do. However, some extra things to think about:

- Do you have error handling in case a negative value is inserted?
- Do you have error handling or is it OK for the resulting quantity value to be negative?

I am assuming these are handled in some a stored procedure or app code, if not, you may want to change this trigger to a BEFORE trigger, do some data sanitization and insert if the data passes the tests

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_MyTrigger
ON TableB
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE  TableA
    SET     Quantity = a.Quantity - b.Quantity
    FROM    TableA a
            JOIN inserted b
                ON a.LotNum = b.LotNum
END
```

MySQL variant:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_myTrigger AFTER INSERT ON TableB
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE  TableA
    SET     Quantity = Quantity - new.Quantity
    WHERE   TableA.LotNum = new.LotNum
END
```